# Choose how many decimals

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm having some issues with decimals, the user is supposed to put in a decimal number eg. (1.97683) and then choose how many decimals he wants to recive, so in this case if he chose 3 he would get the number (1.977).

I just can't get this to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Math.Round(nr, 3) which works but only for number three, the point is to let the user put in how many decimals he/she wants

Comment: capture your decimal precision in a variable and pass it to Math.Round - Math.Round(n, p);

Comment: It you want to return a string, take a look at String.Format().

Answer (score 1):

I use ToString overload to round and display a value. In your case It should be

`var result = value.ToString("0.###")`

Its much better to use that way instead of Math.Round, because sometimes it may give you bad result.

Answer (score -2):

Try this for truncate :

```
value = Math.Truncate(100 * value) / 100;
```

Or use `Math.Round` to round the number to chosen number of decimals :

```
value = Math.Round(value, digits);
```

Comment: And what will this do?

Comment: Truncate as he asked to 2 digits, he can replace 100 with 10 times the number of decimals chosen. I edited for rounding number.